# Yeoman angular generator: where does the appname get stored?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I created a project using yeoman, and i realized that I put the word "app" at the end of the name when i was creating it, which now results in all new generations within this project to be have two `app`s at the end, like `angular.module('myProjectAppApp')`

I've looked around in the files of the project, but i cant seem to find where that appname value was set. any help?

Comment: what you do mean by appname value? Angular adds App to module to avoid collision with Controllers, Services etc. Have a look at <body> inside index.html ng-app="XXXApp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generators use the name value in bower.json. Change that and you should be good to go.